# TSQL Updating record ID after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that takes data from a table and creates a record in another table in the following structure:

```
TableA = Source Data
TableB = Destination 1
```

First, we query all the data we need from the source table and insert it into `TableB`. This table has an `identity` called `recordID`.

This is done through an `INSERT` from a `Select` statement which could contain a variable amount of records.

When this is complete, I need to update a column in `TableA` called `TableBRef` with the `recordID` that was created from the insert in `TableB`.

I tried using `Scope_Identity()` but because its inserting multiple records, it only gets the ID of the last record.

I also tried to create a SQLFiddle but it appears the site is having issues as I am getting the error `Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.:` on even the sample fiddle.

Any recommendations to be able to accomplish what I am needing?

**Update:**

Here is some example code since SQLFiddle is down:

```
-- This is our source data
DECLARE @source TABLE (recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), name VARCHAR(100), phone VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @source(name , phone)
VALUES (
'Bob Desk', '123-456-7899',
'Don Mouse', '123-456-5555',
'Mike Keyboard', '123-456-7899',
'Billy Power', '122-222-1134'
)

-- This is the first step in the process - Inserting the records into our table
DECLARE @data1 TABLE (recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, sourceID INT NULL)
SELECT name, phone
FROM @source;

-- Based on some condition, we take records from @data1 and insert them into @data2
DECLARE @data2 TABLE (recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(20) NOT null)
INSERT INTO @data2( name, phone)
SELECT name, phone
FROM @data1
WHERE phone <> '123-456-5555'

-- I now need to update @data1 with the recordID that was created from inserting the data into @data2
UPDATE @data1 SET SOURCEID = 'blah'
```

Comment: use an output clause to get the new id's of the records being inserted.

Comment: Having a list of all the ID's is one thing but knowing which record they are associated with is where I am stuck. If I did the output on `@data2` I will have a list of ids that were inserted. I would then need to know which record came from the `@data1` record in order to be able to update it right ?

Comment: Add a column to data2 with the recordid from data1 and you can use that to join the data

Answer (score 0):

Lets setup some tables:

```
DECLARE @source TABLE 
(
    recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    sourceID INT
);
```

This will store all of the updates coming out of the insert statement:

```
DECLARE @NewRecord TABLE 
(
    recordID INT, 
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    phone VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Now we insert the records, and we output the updated record into a table variable to get the new id's:

```
INSERT INTO @source (name, phone)
OUTPUT inserted.recordid, inserted.name, inserted.phone INTO @NewRecord
VALUES 
('Bob Desk', '123-456-7899'),
('Don Mouse', '123-456-5555'),
('Mike Keyboard', '123-456-7899'),
('Billy Power', '122-222-1134')
```

Here is the output:

```
SELECT * FROM @NewRecord

recordID    name    phone
1   Bob Desk    123-456-7899
2   Don Mouse   123-456-5555
3   Mike Keyboard   123-456-7899
4   Billy Power 122-222-1134
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data in the source table comes from a 3rd party and contains a nullable field called `sourceID`. So that table has a `PK` called `recordID` and a column called `sourceID`. I never insert data into the `@source` table, I only update it. Once the record has been created in `@NewRecord` I need to UPDATE the source table and say "This ID is why I created the new record, and THIS ID is the record it created in the `@newRecord` table. Does that make sense?

Comment: Kevin, you answered the same question twice. Please delete one of the questions--or you can let the community decide which one to delete.

Comment: I left this old one just to show the output clause for pulling the new id's from the input record.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase when we are inserting data into data2 with new identity column so we lost source record id so I used name and phone to find what I had inserted --this might not work properly if there are duplicate name and phone seems like there is some design flaw.
but here is some thing you can try this below

```
-- This is our source data
DECLARE @source TABLE (recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), name VARCHAR(100), phone VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @source(name , phone)
VALUES (
'Bob Desk', '123-456-7899'),
('Don Mouse', '123-456-5555'),
('Mike Keyboard', '123-456-7899'),
('Billy Power', '122-222-1134')

-- This is the first step in the process - Inserting the records into our table
DECLARE @data1 TABLE (recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, sourceID INT NULL)
--Capture inserts using another table 
DECLARE @cdcapture1 TABLE (recordID INT , name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(20) NOT null)
INSERT INTO @data1(name,phone)
OUTPUT Inserted.recordID,Inserted.name,Inserted.phone INTO @cdcapture1
SELECT name, phone
FROM @source;


--Capture inserts using another table 
DECLARE @cdcapture2 TABLE (recordID INT , name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(20) NOT null)

-- Based on some condition, we take records from @data1 and insert them into @data2
DECLARE @data2 TABLE (recordID INT IDENTITY(1,1), name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(20) NOT null)
INSERT INTO @data2( name, phone)
OUTPUT Inserted.*  INTO @cdcapture2
SELECT name, phone
FROM @cdcapture1 c1
--WHERE phone <> '123-456-5555'

-- Becuase when we are inserting data into data2 with new identity column so we lost source record id 
UPDATE  d1 
SET d1.sourceid = c2.recordid
FROM @data1 d1 INNER JOIN @cdcapture1 c1 ON d1.recordID = c1.recordID
INNER JOIN @cdcapture2 c2 ON c2.NAME = c1.NAME AND c2.phone = c1.phone


SELECT * FROM @data1
```

Answer (score 0):

-- This is our source data

```
DECLARE @source TABLE 
(
    recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    phone VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @source(name , phone)
VALUES 
('Bob Desk', '123-456-7899'),
('Don Mouse', '123-456-5555'),
('Mike Keyboard', '123-456-7899'),
('Billy Power', '122-222-1134');
```

-- This is the first step in the process - Inserting the records into our table

```
DECLARE @data1 TABLE 
(
    recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    sourceID INT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @data1 (name, phone )
SELECT name, phone
FROM @source;
```

-- Based on some condition, we take records from @data1 and insert them into @data2

```
DECLARE @data2 TABLE 
(
    recordID INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    phone VARCHAR(20) NOT null,
    data1recid INT
)

INSERT INTO @data2( name, phone, data1recid)
SELECT name, phone, recordID
FROM @data1
WHERE phone <> '123-456-5555'
```

-- I now need to update @data1 with the recordID that was created from inserting the data into @data2

```
UPDATE m
    set m.sourceID = d.recordID
FROM @data1 m
INNER JOIN @data2 d
    ON m.recordID = d.data1recid
```

Here is the output:

```
SELECT * FROM @data1

recordID    name    phone   sourceID
1   Bob Desk    123-456-7899    1
2   Don Mouse   123-456-5555    NULL
3   Mike Keyboard   123-456-7899    2
4   Billy Power 122-222-1134    3
```

Is this more along the lines of what you needed?